# Procfile calling inside a folder doesn't work

Tags: node.js, heroku, procfile

In the Procfile, `worker: node bot.js` works fine, but if I move the file in a folder, then how would I format it? People have said to use `worker: node folder/bot.js` but that hasnt been working, and I have been getting this:

```
 !     If you are trying to deploy a Node.js application, ensure that this
 !    file is present at the top level directory. This directory has the
 !    following files:
 !     
 !    folder/
 !    log.py
 !    Procfile
 !    README.md
 !    requirements.txt
 !    runtime.txt
 !    status.py
```

So I assume it isn't looking inside the folder, but I do not know why, does anyone have an answer? Thanks to anyone who can help!

Edit: my overall goal is just to have 2 different javascript scripts running at the same time, and since javascript uses those action,node, etc. folders, I can't seem to have 2 working at the same time. I assume doing this folder thing will work but if there is ano0ther solution ill take it

Comment: Have you tried `worker: node ./folder/bot.js`?

Comment: yea just tested it, doesn't work...  it doesn't give that same error though interestingly. Im using this for discord bots so idk if that changes anything but the bots are offline and logs and everything else just say its suceeded